# Android: Adding text to a View

Tags: android, user-interface, view

I'm trying to add a text element to a view that's been created. I've found some answers online, but haven't been able to tailor them. I'm using the TouchPaint example code. Every-time I run the app with the text element, the app fails. Would appreciate some help.

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create and attach the view that is responsible for painting.
    mView = new MyView(this);
    setContentView(mView);
    mView.requestFocus();
    TextView tvX= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.pointSize);
    tvX.setText("TestText");
    // Restore the fading option if we are being thawed from a
    // previously saved state.  Note that we are not currently remembering
    // the contents of the bitmap.
    mFading = savedInstanceState != null ? savedInstanceState.getBoolean("fading", true) : true;
}
```

View class

```
public class MyView extends View {
    private static final int FADE_ALPHA = 0x06;
    private static final int MAX_FADE_STEPS = 256/FADE_ALPHA + 4;
    private Bitmap mBitmap;k
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private final Rect mRect = new Rect();
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private final Paint mFadePaint;
    private boolean mCurDown;
    private int mCurX;
    private int mCurY;
    private float mCurPressure;
    private float mCurSize;
    private int mCurWidth;
    private int mFadeSteps = MAX_FADE_STEPS;
    public MyView(Context c) {
        super(c);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
        mFadePaint = new Paint();
        mFadePaint.setDither(true);
        mFadePaint.setARGB(FADE_ALPHA, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```

XML

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${packageName}.${activityClass}" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pointSize"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You're not inflating your XML anywhere? How's it even being used?

The app can't find the TextView because there pointSize id isn't included anywhere in the view hierarchy of your `MyView` object.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I realize that, but I'm unaware how to do that. I'm using this custom view, and I would like to add the text element to the custom view from the XML. Would appreciate any suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(this);
tvX.setText("TestText");
lv .addView(tvX);
setContentView(lv);
```

Comment: I'm using a Relative layout. Just did an edit with the full XML file. Should I just change LinearLayout with Relative layout?

Comment: Here LinearLayout is just created Pragmatically to set the textview.

Comment: I've added the code you posted above but the app still crashes.                                                                    `mView = new MyView(this);`
        `setContentView(mView);`
        `mView.requestFocus();`
 ` TextView tvX=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.pointSize);`
  `LinearLayout lv = new LinearLayout(this);`
  `tvX.setText("TestText");`
  `lv .addView(tvX);`
  `setContentView(lv);`

Comment: I'm still stuck on this. I'm still in a beginner in Android. Can you tell me how to try what you suggested. Thanks a lot in advance!